# Maven publishing artefacts to remote repository and using $release in the artefact version

Tags: maven, jenkins

Wondering how people manage their project artefacts through an environment lifecycle of say DEV - AQA - CQA - RELEASE and if there's some best practices to follow.

I use a Jenkins build server to build my projects (code checkout then maven build). My artefacts all have version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and are published to a local .m2 repo on the build server. There are also Jenkins jobs that rebuild the DEV system (on the same server) using those artefacts. The project build is automated whenever someone checks in code. The DEV build is automated on a nightly basis.

At some point, my lead developer determines that our project is fit to go to AQA (the first level of testing environment on a different server).

For this I need to mark the artefacts as version 1.0.0-1 and publish to a remote AQA repository (it's actually a Nexus repo).

The Maven deploy plugin sounds like the right approach, but how do I change the version number to be effectively 1.0.0-$release (where $release is just an incrementing number starting from 1)? Would Maven/Nexus be able to manage the value of $release, or would I need a simple properties file in my project to store/update the last used $release.

Furthermore, someone tests AQA and determines its fit to move on to CQA (second testing env). This is 'promote to AQA'. So my requirement is to copy the artefact from the AQA Nexus repo and publish to the CQA Nexus repo.

Likewise, after CQA, there'd be a 'promote to RELEASE' job too.

I think the version value remains unchanged during the 'promote' phases. I'd expect the AQA repo to see all versions 1-50, but CQA only 25 and 50, then RELEASE only 50, for example.

I can find loads of info about Maven plugins/goals/phases, but very little about a prescriptive method on how or where to use outside of the immediate development environment.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Staging/promoting is out of scope for Maven. Once deployed/uploaded to a remote repository, that system is responsible for the completion of the release cycle. Read this chapter about staging: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html if you use Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Build numbers are just that **build numbers**.  They are not promotion / staging numbers.

You should come up with another means of tracking your promotions, because otherwise one might get confused in "knowing" that build 10.1.4-2 is the same as 10.1.4-6.  Certainly, all of the Maven related software *will* see those two builds as different builds.

In addition, if a person "grabs" the wrong copy of the build, the way you are managing staging within your build number will *increase* confusion.  As if you don't kill all of the 10.1.4-2 builds, then someone might get a copy of that not realizing that the build has been promoted to 10.1.4-6.  This means that for the "last" staging number to be the most likely one to be grabbed, you must do two things (which are impossible in combination)

1. Remove all the old staging numbers, updating them to the new ones.
2. Ensure that no copy of an old staging number escaped the update.

Since people generally can copy files without being tracked, or said files might not be reachable at time up "update", or timing between reaching all the files cannot be simultaneous, such a system is doomed to fail.

Instead, I recommend (if you must track by file), placing the same file in different "staging directories".  This defines release gateways by whether the file exists in a certain directory, and makes it clear that it is the same file that is going through the entire process.  In addition, it becomes easy to have various stages of verification poll their respective directories (and you can write Jenkins tasks to promote from one directory to another, if you really wish).